# First activity is called after coming in foreground from background

Tags: android, background

In my application, I am finishing my first activity when I move to the next activity like this:

```
if(className.equals("com.tritonhk.android.LoginActivity"))
            startActivityForResult(in, 1);
        //loadingrelative.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        displayVal = 0;
        Helper.IsFullSync = false;
        LoginActivity.this.finish();
```

So that when I go in background from any other activity and come back in foreground then that activity must be called by which we went in background.

It is happening in some cases but If I remain in background for more then 10 minutes then my first activity's `oncreate` method is called.

It seems that dalvik is killing my application process that is why when I click on my application icon then its new instance is created and hence its `onCreate` is called.

Please suggest me what should be the better approach for this.

**EDIT**  Problem solved partially. Now with `android:launchMode = "standard"` behaves normally but not in first attempt. I mean when I install the app and run it and went to background and come back to foreground then it does not work but from the second time it works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do u have `android:launchMode="standard"` for the `activity` which is called while launching the app? If not add this line.

Comment: No I dont have it in my launcher activity. What this tag means?

Comment: When I run the app directly from my eclipse it works.But when I export it by signing with developer key and install it to device it does not work. Don't know what is happening???

Answer (score 2):

Since you are finishing your current activity which launches subactivity means you don't want the task to retain root activity on re launch  , 
you want to start from where you left ,you may use android:alwaysRetainTaskState which will retain state of task since it is useful for root activity only so you have to start your subactivity in a new task using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK intentfilter flag.